# Cannot use EWS.dll with ExchangeWebServices namespace

Tags: dll, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

This link outlines what I am trying to do

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa494212(v=exchg.140).aspx

HOW do I get the right DLL for this? This is really hard for some reason....

I am trying to use the class

GetUserAvailabilityResponseType

the only DLLs I can get that have anything to do with exchange are

Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

For a while I thought this was EWS.dll, however it does not contain the namespace 'ExchangeWebServices'. Which I need to access the class, it only contains the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data namespace which does not have my required classes.

can some please tell me how I can get the right namespace?

Thanks.

Comment: If you browse around on that same website, this will lead you to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220499.aspx Is your system properly set up as described there?

Comment: Yup, looked at that, it's still using the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data and my methods aren't in there. It's really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right DLL, but the link you refer to is a type defined for the older EWS Proxy classes, which don't have a DLL per se, but are defined via the `wsdl` command.  Everything being equal, you don't want to use these old classes, but rather the new EWS Managed API, which is provided by the DLL in question.  The equivalent functionality (availability) is provided there, and a placed to start looking into how to use it is [here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.EXCHANGE.WEBSERVICES.DATA.EXCHANGESERVICE.GETUSERAVAILABILITY%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Answer (score -1):

```
public partial class ServiceDialog : IDisposable
    {
        ExchangeService _service = null;
        public ExchangeService CurrentService
        {
            get
            {
                return _service;
            }
            set
            {
                _service = value;
            }
        }
        EwsEditorAppSettings _CurrentAppSettings = null;
        public EwsEditorAppSettings CurrentAppSettings
        {
            get
            {
                return _CurrentAppSettings;
            }
            set
            {
                _CurrentAppSettings = value;
            }
        }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
    private List<ConnectingIdType> connectingIdCombo = new List<ConnectingIdType>();
    private List<ExchangeVersion> exchangeVersionCombo = new List<ExchangeVersion>();

    public ServiceDialog()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
        //EwsEditorAppSettings oAppSettings = null;
        //ExchangeService service = null;
        //DialogResult result = ServiceDialog.ShowDialog(ref service, ref oAppSettings);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A passed ExchangeService can be displayed for editing or a new
    /// service will be returned after created using this dialog.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">ExchangeService to be returned or displayed</param>
    /// <returns>DialogResult indicating the user action which closed the dialog</returns>
    public void ShowDialog(ref ExchangeService service, ref  EwsEditorAppSettings oAppSettings)
    {
        ServiceDialog dialog = new ServiceDialog();

        if (service != null)
        {
            dialog.CurrentService = service;
        }

        if (oAppSettings != null)
        {
            dialog.CurrentAppSettings = oAppSettings;
        }
        service = dialog.CurrentService;

        oAppSettings = dialog.CurrentAppSettings;

        //return res;
    }

    //private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    public void OnstartLogon( string strusername,string strpassword,string strdomain)
    {
        // Validation for credential input...
        string UserName = "";
        string Password = "";
        string ServerName= "";
        string DomainName= "";

        string strMakeUrl = "https://" + strdomain + "/EWS/exchange.asmx";

        Uri ExchangeUrl = new Uri(strMakeUrl);


        UserName = strusername;
        Password = strpassword;
        DomainName = strdomain;


        //if (rdoCredentialsUserSpecified.Checked && (txtUserName.Text.Length == 0 || txtPassword.Text.Length == 0))
        //{
        //    ErrorDialog.ShowInfo(DisplayStrings.MSG_SPECIFY_CREDS);
        //    return;
        //}

        //// Validation for Autodiscover input...

        //if (this.rdoAutodiscoverEmail.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Text))
        //{
        //    ErrorDialog.ShowInfo(DisplayStrings.MSG_SERVICE_REQ);
        //    return;
        //}

        //// Validation for URL input...
        //if (this.rdoServiceUrl.Checked && String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ExchangeServiceURLText.Text))
        //{
        //    ErrorDialog.ShowInfo(DisplayStrings.MSG_SERVICE_REQ);
        //    return;
        //}

        //// Validation for Impersonation input...
        //if (this.ImpersonationCheck.Checked && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text) || !this.connectingIdCombo.SelectedItem.HasValue))
        //{
        //    ErrorDialog.ShowInfo(DisplayStrings.MSG_IMPERSON_REQ);
        //    return;
        //}

        try
        {
            //Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;

            EwsProxyFactory.RequestedExchangeVersion = ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013;// exchangeVersionCombo.SelectedItem;

            EwsProxyFactory.OverrideTimezone = GlobalSettings.OverrideTimezone;
            EwsProxyFactory.SelectedTimeZoneId = GlobalSettings.SelectedTimeZoneId;

            EwsProxyFactory.AllowAutodiscoverRedirect = GlobalSettings.AllowAutodiscoverRedirect;

            EwsProxyFactory.UseDefaultCredentials = false;// this.rdoCredentialsDefaultWindows.Checked;
            //if (this.rdoCredentialsDefaultWindows.Checked)
            //{
            //    EwsProxyFactory.AuthenticationMethod = RequestedAuthType.DefaultAuth;
            //}

            EwsProxyFactory.CredentialsUserSpecified = true;// this.rdoCredentialsUserSpecified.Checked;

            //if (this.rdoCredentialsUserSpecified.Checked)
            if(true)
            {
                EwsProxyFactory.AuthenticationMethod = RequestedAuthType.SpecifiedCredentialsAuth;
            }

            if (false/*this.rdoCredentialsOAuth.Checked*/)
            {
                EwsProxyFactory.AuthenticationMethod = RequestedAuthType.oAuth;
            }

            // MailboxBeingAccessed
            switch (EwsProxyFactory.AuthenticationMethod)
            {
                case RequestedAuthType.DefaultAuth:
                    //AutodiscoverEmailText.Text = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
                    break;
                case RequestedAuthType.SpecifiedCredentialsAuth:
                    //if (this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
                    //    EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed = this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Trim();
                    //else
                    //    EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed = this.txtUserName.Text.Trim();
                    //break;

                    EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed = UserName;
                    break;
                case RequestedAuthType.oAuth:
                    //EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed = this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Trim();  // override later in ewsproxyfactory
                    EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed = UserName;  // override later in ewsproxyfactory
                    break;
            }

            //if (this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
            //    EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed = this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Trim();
            //if (this.ImpersonationCheck.Checked) // Override
            //    EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed = ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text.Trim();


            EwsProxyFactory.UserImpersonationSelected = false;// this.ImpersonationCheck.Checked;
            //EwsProxyFactory.UserToImpersonate = this.ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text  // set below
            EwsProxyFactory.ImpersonationType = "SmtpAddress";//this.connectingIdCombo.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
            EwsProxyFactory.ImpersonatedId = "";//this.ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text.Trim();


            EwsProxyFactory.UseoAuth = false;//this.rdoCredentialsOAuth.Checked;
            EwsProxyFactory.oAuthRedirectUrl = "https://microsoft.com/EwsEditor";//this.txtOAuthRedirectUri.Text.Trim();
            EwsProxyFactory.oAuthClientId = "0e4bf2e2-aa7d-46e8-aa12-263adeb3a62b";//this.txtOAuthAppId.Text.Trim();
            EwsProxyFactory.oAuthServerName = ServerName;//this.txtOAuthServerName.Text.Trim();
            EwsProxyFactory.oAuthAuthority = "https://login.windows.net/common";//this.txtOAuthAuthority.Text.Trim();


            EwsProxyFactory.EnableScpLookup = GlobalSettings.EnableScpLookups;
            EwsProxyFactory.PreAuthenticate = GlobalSettings.PreAuthenticate;

            EwsProxyFactory.OverrideTimeout = GlobalSettings.OverrideTimeout;
            EwsProxyFactory.Timeout = GlobalSettings.Timeout;
            EwsProxyFactory.UserAgent = GlobalSettings.UserAgent;

            EwsProxyFactory.UserName = UserName;//this.txtUserName.Text.Trim();
            // EwsProxyFactory.Password = this.txtPassword.Text.Trim();   // Don't keep.
            EwsProxyFactory.Domain = DomainName;//this.txtDomain.Text.Trim();

            EwsProxyFactory.SetDefaultProxy = GlobalSettings.SetDefaultProxy;
            EwsProxyFactory.BypassProxyForLocalAddress = GlobalSettings.BypassProxyForLocalAddress;
            EwsProxyFactory.SpecifyProxySettings = GlobalSettings.SpecifyProxySettings;
            EwsProxyFactory.ProxyServerName = GlobalSettings.ProxyServerName;
            EwsProxyFactory.ProxyServerPort = GlobalSettings.ProxyServerPort;
            EwsProxyFactory.OverrideProxyCredentials = GlobalSettings.OverrideProxyCredentials;
            EwsProxyFactory.ProxyServerUser = GlobalSettings.ProxyServerUser;
            EwsProxyFactory.ProxyServerPassword = GlobalSettings.ProxyServerPassword;
            EwsProxyFactory.ProxyServerDomain = GlobalSettings.ProxyServerDomain;





            //EwsProxyFactory.EwsUrl = this.rdoAutodiscoverEmail.Checked ?
            //    null : new Uri(ExchangeServiceURLText.Text.Trim());



            EwsProxyFactory.EwsUrl = ExchangeUrl;

            //EwsProxyFactory.UserToImpersonate = this.ImpersonationCheck.Checked ?
            //    new ImpersonatedUserId(this.connectingIdCombo.SelectedItem.Value, this.ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text.Trim()) : null;

            EwsProxyFactory.UserToImpersonate =  null;

            EwsProxyFactory.SetXAnchorMailbox = false;//this.chkSetXAnchorMailbox.Checked;
            EwsProxyFactory.XAnchorMailbox = null;//this.txtXAnchorMailbox.Text.Trim();

            EwsProxyFactory.SetXPublicFolderMailbox = null;//;this.chkSetXPublicFolderMailbox.Checked;
            EwsProxyFactory.XPublicFolderMailbox = "";//this.txtXPublicFolderMailbox.Text.Trim();




            EwsProxyFactory.EnableAdditionalHeader1 = GlobalSettings.EnableAdditionalHeader1;
            EwsProxyFactory.AdditionalHeader1 = GlobalSettings.AdditionalHeader1;
            EwsProxyFactory.AdditionalHeaderValue1 = GlobalSettings.AdditionalHeaderValue1;
            EwsProxyFactory.EnableAdditionalHeader2 = GlobalSettings.EnableAdditionalHeader2;
            EwsProxyFactory.AdditionalHeader2 = GlobalSettings.AdditionalHeader2;
            EwsProxyFactory.AdditionalHeaderValue2 = GlobalSettings.AdditionalHeaderValue2;
            EwsProxyFactory.EnableAdditionalHeader3 = GlobalSettings.EnableAdditionalHeader3;
            EwsProxyFactory.AdditionalHeader3 = GlobalSettings.AdditionalHeader3;
            EwsProxyFactory.AdditionalHeaderValue3 = GlobalSettings.AdditionalHeaderValue3;

            EwsProxyFactory.AddTimeZoneContext = GlobalSettings.AddTimeZoneContext;
            EwsProxyFactory.SelectedTimeZoneContextId = GlobalSettings.SelectedTimeZoneContextId;


            //EwsProxyFactory.ServiceEmailAddress = this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Trim();
            EwsProxyFactory.UseAutoDiscover = false;//this.rdoAutodiscoverEmail.Checked;

            //EwsProxyFactory.ServiceCredential = rdoCredentialsUserSpecified.Checked ?
            //   new NetworkCredential(
            //       this.txtUserName.Text.Trim(),
            //       this.txtPassword.Text.Trim(),  // This will fail on passwords ending with whitespace
            //       this.txtDomain.Text.Trim()) :
            //   null;

            // ----- Set Credentials ----
            EwsProxyFactory.ServiceCredential = null;
            EwsProxyFactory.ServiceNetworkCredential = null;

            if (false/*rdoCredentialsDefaultWindows.Checked*/)
            {
                EwsProxyFactory.ServiceCredential = (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                EwsProxyFactory.ServiceNetworkCredential = (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            }

            if (true/*rdoCredentialsUserSpecified.Checked*/)
            {
                NetworkCredential oNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(
                   UserName/*this.txtUserName.Text.Trim()*/,
                   Password,/*this.txtPassword.Text.Trim()*/  // This will fail on passwords ending with whitespace
                   DomainName);/*this.txtDomain.Text.Trim())*/

                EwsProxyFactory.ServiceCredential = oNetworkCredential;

                EwsProxyFactory.ServiceNetworkCredential = oNetworkCredential;
            }


            if (false/*this.rdoCredentialsOAuth.Checked*/)
            {
                AuthenticationHelper oAH = new AuthenticationHelper();

                EwsProxyFactory.ServiceCredential = oAH.Do_OAuth(ref EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed, ref EwsProxyFactory.AccountAccessingMailbox,
                  EwsProxyFactory.oAuthAuthority, EwsProxyFactory.oAuthClientId, EwsProxyFactory.oAuthRedirectUrl, EwsProxyFactory.oAuthServerName);

                //EwsProxyFactory.AccountAccessingMailbox
                //EwsProxyFactory.MailboxBeingAccessed = EwsProxyFactory.AccountAccessingMailbox;
            }

            // ----    Autodiscover    ----

            if (false/*this.rdoAutodiscoverEmail.Checked*/)
            {
                EwsProxyFactory.DoAutodiscover();
            }

            // ----    New service & app settings    ----

            CurrentService = EwsProxyFactory.CreateExchangeService();


            // ----    Save settings    ----
            EwsEditorAppSettings oAppSettings = new EwsEditorAppSettings();
            EwsProxyFactory.SetAppSettingsFromProxyFactory(ref oAppSettings);
            CurrentAppSettings = oAppSettings;

            //CurrentAppSettings.MailboxBeingAccessed = EwsProxyFactory.AccountAccessingMailbox;
            // CurrentAppSettings

            // EwsProxyFactory.AccountAccessingMailbox

            // ----    Do a basic test to be sure that the mailbox can be reached with an EWS call   ----
            CurrentService.TestExchangeService();

            CurrentService.OnSerializeCustomSoapHeaders += m_Service_OnSerializeCustomSoapHeaders;



            //DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        finally
        {
            //Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
        }
    }

    private Uri Uri(string p)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    ///// <summary>
    /////  This is used for adding soap headers not exposed in the EWS Managed API
    ///// </summary>
    ///// <param name="oRequest"></param>
    public void m_Service_OnSerializeCustomSoapHeaders(XmlWriter writer)
    {

        // Add TimeZoneDefinition...
        // http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2014/04/23/ews-missing-soap-headers-when-using-the-ews-managed-api.aspx

        if (EwsProxyFactory.AddTimeZoneContext == true)
        {
            writer.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine + "    <t:TimeZoneContext><t:TimeZoneDefinition Id=\"" + GlobalSettings.SelectedTimeZoneContextId + "\"/></t:TimeZoneContext>" + Environment.NewLine);
        }

    }

    private void ChkCredentials_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ChkImpersonation_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text = string.Empty;

        //this.connectingIdCombo.Enabled = ImpersonationCheck.Checked;
        //ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Enabled = ImpersonationCheck.Checked;
        //lblImpId.Enabled = ImpersonationCheck.Checked;
        //lblImpIdType.Enabled = ImpersonationCheck.Checked;           
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Display the GetMailboxNameDialog to get the SMTP address and
    /// perform Autodiscover operation to get the EWS service URL.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The parameter is not used.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The parameter is not used.</param>
    private void BtnAutodiscover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Mailbox mbx = null;

        //// If the result isn't OK do nothing.
        //if (GetMailboxNameDialog.ShowDialog(ref mbx) != DialogResult.OK)
        //{
        //    return;
        //}

        //try
        //{
        //    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        //    ExchangeService tempService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        //    tempService.TraceEnabled = true;
        //    tempService.TraceEnablePrettyPrinting = true;
        //    tempService.TraceListener = new EWSEditor.Logging.EwsTraceListener();

        //    if (GlobalSettings.AllowAutodiscoverRedirect)
        //    {
        //        tempService.AutodiscoverUrl(
        //            mbx.Address,
        //            delegate(string url) { return true; });
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        tempService.AutodiscoverUrl(mbx.Address);
        //    }

        //    AutodiscoverEmailText.Text = mbx.Address;
        //    ExchangeServiceURLText.Text = tempService.Url.ToString();
        //}
        //finally
        //{
        //    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        //}
    }

    private void ServiceDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.exchangeVersionCombo.TransformComboBox(this.TempExchangeVersionCombo);
        //this.exchangeVersionCombo.HasEmptyItem = true;
        //this.exchangeVersionCombo.Text = "Exchange2013";

        //this.connectingIdCombo.TransformComboBox(this.TempConnectingIdCombo);
        //this.connectingIdCombo.SelectedItem = ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress;


        //// If CurrentService is already set then we are editing an
        //// existing ExchangeService and need to load it first.
        //if (this.CurrentService != null)
        //{
        //    if (this.CurrentService.Url != null)
        //    {
        //        this.rdoAutodiscoverEmail.Checked = false;
        //        this.ExchangeServiceURLText.Text = this.CurrentService.Url.ToString();
        //    }

        //    this.exchangeVersionCombo.SelectedItem = this.CurrentService.RequestedServerVersion;

        //    if (this.CurrentService.Credentials != null)
        //    {
        //        this.rdoCredentialsUserSpecified.Checked = true;

        //        NetworkCredential cred = this.CurrentService.GetNetworkCredential();
        //        this.txtUserName.Text = cred.UserName;
        //        this.txtPassword.Text = cred.Password;
        //        this.txtDomain.Text = cred.Domain;
        //    }

        //    if (this.CurrentService.ImpersonatedUserId != null)
        //    {
        //        this.ImpersonationCheck.Checked = true;

        //        this.connectingIdCombo.SelectedItem = this.CurrentService.ImpersonatedUserId.IdType;
        //        this.ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text = this.CurrentService.ImpersonatedUserId.Id;
        //    }
        //}

        //SetAutoDiscoverSelection();

        //SetAuthEnablement();

    }

    private void chkUseSpecifiedTimezone_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnOptions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // OptionsDialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void cmboTimeZoneIds_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void rdoAutodiscoverEmail_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SetAutoDiscoverSelection();
    }

    private void SetAutoDiscoverSelection()
    {
        if (true/*this.rdoAutodiscoverEmail.Checked == true*/)
        {
            //this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Text = string.Empty;
            //this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Enabled = true;
            //this.lblAutodiscoverEmailDesc.Enabled = true;
            //this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Focus();

            //this.ExchangeServiceURLText.Enabled = false;
            //this.lblExchangeServiceURLTextDesc.Enabled = false;
            //this.btnDefault365Settings.Enabled = false;
        }

        if (false/*this.rdoServiceUrl.Checked == true*/)
        {
            //this.ExchangeServiceURLText.Text = string.Empty;
            //this.ExchangeServiceURLText.Enabled = true;
            //this.lblExchangeServiceURLTextDesc.Enabled = true;
            //this.ExchangeServiceURLText.Focus();

            //this.btnDefault365Settings.Enabled = true;

            //this.AutodiscoverEmailText.Enabled = false;
            //this.lblAutodiscoverEmailDesc.Enabled = false;


        }
    }

    private void rdoServiceUrl_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetAutoDiscoverSelection();
    }

    private void lblImpId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    //{

    //}

    private void txtDefaultSmtp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // AutodiscoverEmailText.Text = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
    }

    //private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    //{

    //}

    private void btnDefault365Settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ExchangeServiceURLText.Text = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
    }

    private void btnDefaultSmtp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // AutodiscoverEmailText.Text = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
    }

    private void TempConnectingIdCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void chkSetXAnchorMailbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //txtXAnchorMailbox.Enabled = chkSetXAnchorMailbox.Checked;

        //// Default ImpersonatedIdTextBox ImpersonationCheck
        //if (chkSetXAnchorMailbox.Checked == true && txtXAnchorMailbox.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        //{
        //    if (ImpersonationCheck.Checked == true)
        //    {
        //        if (ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text.Contains("@"))
        //            txtXAnchorMailbox.Text = ImpersonatedIdTextBox.Text;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {

        //        if (rdoAutodiscoverEmail.Checked == true && AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Contains("@"))
        //        {
        //            txtXAnchorMailbox.Text = AutodiscoverEmailText.Text;
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            if (txtUserName.Text.Contains("@"))
        //                txtXAnchorMailbox.Text = txtUserName.Text;
        //        }
        //    }

        //}
    }

    private void rdoCredentialsUserSpecified_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SetAuthEnablement();



    }

    private void SetAuthEnablement()
    {
        bool bUserSpecified = false;/*this.rdoCredentialsUserSpecified.Checked*/;
        bool bUseOAuth = false;//this.rdoCredentialsOAuth.Checked;

        //txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
        //txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;
        //txtDomain.Text = string.Empty;

        //txtUserName.Enabled = bUserSpecified;
        //txtPassword.Enabled = bUserSpecified;
        //txtDomain.Enabled = bUserSpecified;
        //lblUserName.Enabled = bUserSpecified;
        //lblPassword.Enabled = bUserSpecified;
        //lblDomain.Enabled = bUserSpecified;

        //if (this.rdoCredentialsUserSpecified.Checked == true)
        //{
        //    if (rdoAutodiscoverEmail.Checked == true)
        //    {
        //        if (txtUserName.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        //        {
        //            if (AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        //            {
        //                txtUserName.Text = AutodiscoverEmailText.Text.Trim();
        //            }
        //        }
        //    }
        //}

        //this.lblOAuthAppId.Enabled = bUseOAuth;
        //this.lblOAuthAuthority.Enabled = bUseOAuth;
        //this.lblOAuthRedirectUri.Enabled = bUseOAuth;
        //this.lblOAuthServerName.Enabled = bUseOAuth;

        //this.txtOAuthAppId.Enabled = bUseOAuth;
        //this.txtOAuthAuthority.Enabled = bUseOAuth;
        //this.txtOAuthRedirectUri.Enabled = bUseOAuth;
        //this.txtOAuthServerName.Enabled = bUseOAuth;
    }

    private void txtOAuthRedirectUri_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void rdoCredentialsOAuth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetAuthEnablement();
    }

    private void rdoCredentialsDefaultWindows_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetAuthEnablement();
    }

    //private void panel3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    //{

    //}

    private void ImpersonatedIdTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnDefaultUserNameSmtp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // this.txtUserName.Text = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
    }

    private void chkSetXPublicFolderMailbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //txtXPublicFolderMailbox.Enabled = chkSetXPublicFolderMailbox.Checked;


    }


    public Uri https { get; set; }
}
```